# A record correct?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have domain in one company, with an specific NS entries, but I don't want changes the NS entries.

The server is in another company with public IP.

If I want to point from my domain to the server, is enough with adding an A record into the domain company, that A entry would point to my public IP.

Is that OK?

How long it takes the changes?

How can I trace the A record propagation?

Comment: The **what** server?  DNS?  HTTP?  SMTP?  FTP?

Comment: @JdeBP: Does it matter? The question is about DNS A records.

Comment: Of course it matters; and _no the question is not_.  You haven't read the part of the question that asks whether adding `A` records is the "OK" thing to do in the first place and have just leapt in with the assumption that it is.

Comment: I'm missing something in that "how it matters" part...DNS doesn't control what ports you have open. If I have mydomain.com and want to ftp to it, I just ftp to mydomain.com, and if I want to hit the web server, I open http://mydomain.com...?

Answer (score 2):

Use your domain companies tools to create an A record that points to the public IP address of your server. The changes can take quite some time perhaps up to 72 hours for global coverage but would generally be less. You can try tools like [this](http://www.whatsmydns.net/) to see how your A record is propagating.

Comment: I checked the propragation as you said, but how can I see, but is already progated for the old IP, how can I be sure that the new IP is ready for being propagated? In my case I adde so. www.domain.com A ip. Is that right, did not touch the ns servers.

Comment: If you change the IP address as it propagates you should see it change in that tool.

Comment: The new IP once changed is propogated according to individual caching configured on other DNS servers. You have no control over that. It can take anywhere from immediate (if you're querying the servers on which the changes were made) to a couple days for worldwide propagation. Make the change on the authoritative server and it goes out; you don't "commit the change," so to speak.

Comment: Come on guys. DNS doesn't propagate. Stop propagating the DNS propagation idea.

Comment: @joeqwerty that is a semantics discussion more suited to English.sx :^)

Comment: It's not an issue of semantics. It is absolutely a technical issue. DNS records don't propagate and to say that they do is technically incorrect and perpetuates a long standing misunderstanding of how DNS works. It's the difference between push and pull and it is not a case of semantics or of being pedantic. It is incorrect to tell someone that they have to wait for their A record to propagate and we should all stop implying such.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new A record for a new domain (host) should propagate quite quickly.  Initial queries will go to your nameserver rather than caches.  Changes to that domain will depend on the TTL for the domain.

There may be some delay with synchronizing the nameservers, but many setups use notify.  This will speed things up.

The main problem will be possible negative caching.  This should not be much of a problem, as noone should have been looking for the domain.